# Reference request : upper bound of marginal densities of a SDE with discontinuous coefficient

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the one-dimensional SDE

$$X_t = x+ \int_0^t\frac{\sigma(s,X_s)}{1+{\bf 1}_{\{b(s,X_s)>0\}}}dW_s,\quad \forall t\ge 0,$$

where $W_t$ is a standard BM and $b,\sigma$ are sufficiently regular coefficient functions, e.g. $b,\sigma$ are Lipschitz, bounded and $\inf_{(t,y)}\sigma(t,y)>0$. Suppose the above SDE admits a solution. Can we show $X_t$ has a density $p_t$ for all $t>0$? If so, does there exist $C>c>0$ s.t.

$$p_t(y) \le \dfrac{C}{\sqrt t} \exp\left(-\dfrac{y^2}{ct}\right),\quad \forall t>0,~~ y\in \mathbb R?$$

PS : More precisely, the aim is to show that if $x>0$, there exists  $C>0$ s.t.

$$\mathbb E\left[\min\left(1,h/X_t^2\right){\bf 1}_{\{X_t>0\}}\right]=\int_{(0,\infty)}\min\left(1,\frac{h}{y^2}\right)\mathbb P[X_t\in dy] \le C\frac{\sqrt h}{\sqrt t},\quad \forall h\in (0,1),~ t>0.$$

Obviously, the boundedness of $p_t$ yields my desired inequality.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Absolutely. I have edited

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Right. I've modified everywhere

Comment: I think you want $\sigma $ bounded above, otherwise I'm not sure you would expect this to be the case, e.g.  yo have excluded log-normal, but modify it slightly with say $\sigma(x) = \sqrt{(1 + x^2)} $ and I would expect quite long tails, not sub gaussian.

Comment: @mike Yes. Both $b, \sigma$ are bounded. Do you think we may obtain the upper bound as desired?

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Right. Indeed, whenever the density of $X_t$ exists and bounded, then the inequality holds. I tried to derive the inequality using Ito's formula by approximating $\min(1, h/x^2)$

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Exactly. The constant $C$ should depend on $x$